# Swift -- Audio Recorder/Voice Changer App: How are these functions related?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiorecorder

I have two functions in an audio recorder app I am creating (following a Udacity tutorial.) I am trying to understand how these two functions are related:

```
    @IBAction func recordButton(sender: UIButton) {

    recordB.hidden = true
    inProgress.hidden = false
    stopButtonHide.hidden = false
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let currentDateTime = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"
    let recordingName = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)+".wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    println(filePath)

    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)


    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if(flag) {
        recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()
        recordedAudio.filePathUrl = recorder.url
        recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("stopRecording", sender: recordedAudio)
    } else {
        println("Recording was not succesful")
        recordB.enabled = true
        stopButtonHide.hidden = true
    }

}
```

The first function starts a recording (as I understand it), creates and stores an audio file (names it and gets it a path.) The second function checks to see if the recording is finished. My problem is that I can't see how the two functions connect. How does the second function know to check the recording in the first function? There is a separate class called RecordedAudio.swift that has  two variables:

```
import Foundation

class RecordedAudio: NSObject{
var filePathUrl: NSURL!
var title: String!
}
```

Why do I need this class? What is the purpose of this class (I know it is the model part of MVC but that's it)? I am trying to understand what is going on in my code as it wasn't that clear to me from the tutorial I am following.

Comment: The main question(s) I have here is how does the audio from the first function get passed to the second function: is it that the second function takes whatever audio was being recorded? How does `recorder.url` and `recorder.url.lastPathComponant` work? How do these two items get their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It seems as if `recordedAudio` is a `RecordedAudio` object, thus the need for that class.
2. `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` is ([as stated in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorderDelegate_ProtocolReference/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioRecorderDelegate/audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:)) an `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` method and is automatically...

> called by the system when a recording is stopped or has finished due to reaching its time limit.

In this case, the "recording" would refer to the `AVAudioRecorder` `audioRecorder` you've created in `recordButton:` (and for which you've set its `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` in order to trigger the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:` method).

Comment: So in otherwords `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` is triggered when any `AVAudioRecorder` finishes (that func with its code is executed)? So if I had for some reason two `audioRecorder` objects, it is triggered if either one finishes?

As far is `recorededAudio` being an `RecorededAudio` object, I understand that much but what I don't understand is why I needed to create that class in the first place. Why does that class need its two path related variables? What is that class doing in terms of storing the recorded data and how? Why isn't the original function sufficient for storing the data?

Comment: @JasonHolt yes. As long as you've set the delegates for both.

Comment: What will end up happening is I will end up sending that audio data that is recorded to a new ViewController. So I'm trying to figure out how I went from "This is how you record audio in Swift" to you need another class to store data and a function to check if the audio finished recording and by the way that function that finishes its recording somehow knows and stores that original data in a second class that you created.

Comment: @JasonHolt the whole point of delegate methods is to "somehow know" things. And the url is the url you set while initializing your avaudiorecorder and its lastComponent is simply the last portion of that url (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/lastPathComponent)

Comment: Re-reading your answer after looking over some more documentation makes things more clear. Its because I set the delegate that these two functions communicate to each other, as `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` can't be implemented without the delegate being set. Is the Model part of MVC meant to hold properties of data only or the data itself? It seems like if it was meant to hold data the recordedAudio would need to have the audio file. Thanks for all your help.